# KVM Guest Memory, Cpu status required

Tags: cloud, virtualization, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I am trying to figure out that how Virt-manager (libvirt) finds the CPU performance. Actually i am trying a script to check the CPU and Memory usage status of the GUEST so that i can reach to a LOAD Balancing decision.

PS
Please ignore the LOAD balancing part because it is not that much relevant

Comment: you could call `vmstat` with ssh (public key, non-privileged account).

Comment: @erny Even i found **mpstat** and **iostat** useful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I take it you probably meant statistics instead of performance.

The C API functions to are [virDomainGetCPUStats](http://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt.html#virDomainGetCPUStats) and [virDomainMemoryStats](http://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt.html#virDomainMemoryStats).
Their python counterparts are domain.getCPUStats() and domain.memoryStats().